# Searchbox for Stack Exchange in Android mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

In the desktop view I can do a search in Stack Exchange and it will list out all the various sites where it can find out the term whether it may be Stack Overflow, Linux and Unix, Cryptography etc.

Can you please provide the same search feature in Android mobile app also?

Comment: Oh, i didnt get any duplicate info when i was asking the question from the android phone. Anyways please consider this feature as it will be very helpful in searching contents and providing broad understanding of our searches.